# Does using statement keep a reference to object(s) it receive?

Tags: c#, reference, garbage-collection, using, idisposable

When using "using" statement like this:

```
  using (Global.Instance.BusyLifeTrackerStack.GetNewLifeTracker())
  {
    ...
```

instead of

```
  using (var lt = Global.Instance.BusyLifeTrackerStack.GetNewLifeTracker())
  {
    ...
```

Does "using" statement will keep a reference to the returned object in order to ensure it will not be garbage collected too much earlier?... either if there is no explicit variable declared for it (first sample code)?

Second sample code is clearly fine, but first one???

Any documentation and/or reference to the information would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't be able to call `Dispose` on it.

Comment: A real reference? The garbage collector can't garbage it?

Comment: Yes, the reference `lt` is only for you to use in the block. If you don't need to use it, you don't need to declare it. The using block will dispose the object either way. This is a pattern you see occasionally where the object is only created for temporary side effects that are undone in its Dispose() method. For example, we have a class called WaitCursor that sets the cursor to the wait cursor in the constructor, and restores it in Dispose() to whatever it was previously.

Comment: Yes, a real reference. As Ed suggests, this pattern is often used to do something in the disposal that has a side effect. For example in Razor `using(Html.BeginForm){...}` allows the disposal of the returned object to output the `</form>` tag at the end.

Comment: The [documentation for `using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) says a lot of this, and of course [the C# standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement)

Comment: @HereticMonkey To be fair, it doesn't mention this syntax, I can understand why it's not entirely obvious.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I need an answer to accept it :-) !!!

Comment: I just verified to be sure. I called :     using (Global.Instance.BusyLifeTrackerStack.GetNewLifeTracker())
   {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   }
and "Dispose" was called. Thanks a lots... Yes I know, I should have verified before asked my question... sorry!

Comment: How are you expecting it to be able to call dispose on the object at the end of the using if it doesn't contain any reference to the object?  If it's not holding a reference to it, then how is it going to dispose of the object?

Comment: @Servy, weak ref would be an easy answer :-) ... but it is internal... there could have been many other ways...

Comment: @EricOuellet Then the garbage collector would be destroying an object to which there is subsequent code that needs to access it, which is by definition the *only* thing the GC isn't allowed to do.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I red the documentation before I ask the question and I didn't read the information in it (perhaps I was not enough concentrated?). But it is the first time I read the language reference. Thanks a lots!!! It is very clear there !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the documentation and reference portion of your question:

The [documentation for the `using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) notes:

> The using statement calls the [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose) method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose) is called. Within the `using` block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

As far as the syntax of the first code block goes, the [C# standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement) has the following for the syntax:

> ```cs
> using_statement
>     : 'using' '(' resource_acquisition ')' embedded_statement
>     ;
>
> resource_acquisition
>     : local_variable_declaration
>     | expression
>     ;
> ```

There, you'll note that `resource_acquisition` can be a local variable declaration, or an expression, which is what your first code block uses.

Comment: You got the exact documentation I was looking for. An example wich force the GB to collect inside the using block would have been also a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a real reference is kept so that the `Dispose` method can be called at the end. This pattern is often used to perform some sort of "side effect" in the disposal when you don't explicitly need to access the disposable object inside the `using` block. For example, in Razor `using(Html.BeginForm){...}` allows the disposal of the returned object to output the `</form>` tag at the end.

A trivial example in C# would be:

```
public class MessageGenerator : IDisposable
{
    public MessageGenerator()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("To whom it may concern,");
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks and goodbye.");
    }
}
```

And usage like this:

```
using (new MessageGenerator())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please give me lots of reputation.");
}
```

Would give output like this:

> To whom it may concern,
>
> Please give me lots of reputation
>
> Thanks and goodbye.

Comment: Thanks DavidG, I finally decide to go with Heretic Monkey because I got the exact documentation which explain the behavior. Also, I think that you need to force the garbage colector to collect into the "using" statement block in order to proove the behavior. But thank you very much. I feel a lot better because I do use the pattern without assigning any variable (using "using") pretty much often in my code.

Comment: No, it's not about GC, it's about calling `Dispose`. The `using` statement is really just syntactic sugar around a `try/`finally` block. GC happens later on at an unspecified time.

Comment: I was afraid that my disposable object could have been garbage collected before it reached the finally block and the Dispose method. That's why forcing the GC to collect is, to my opinion, a must to ensure the proper behavior. Either a sample or the documentation would prove it. Heretic found proper documentation.

Comment: No, forcing GC is not required at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQEkDyA3MslAMyYzoDC6A3suk5hVACzoCyAFAJT2NmQtOm4AxAJYAbAKbZ8ABxkA7AEoyAhsG4AiACoyAzgBdsxgB7GdvXnQC+gpg6TOgA=) of what the compiler does behind the scenes. The code bellow:

```
using (File.OpenRead("Test.txt")){}
```

...is transformed to:

```
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("Test.txt");
try
{
}
finally
{
    if (fileStream != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)fileStream).Dispose();
    }
}
```

A variable is declared, that holds a reference to the used object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example (the one from SharpLab). That is an incredible tool that I didn't know its existence. THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!!!!!!